# How to lag dates based on multiple conditions and reseting the lag after it occurs

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, lag

I have a dataframe of station repairs.

The workflow is like this: Mechanics go to a station and they press a button that records an `action` named `release`. After they fix the station, they press the button again and the action is now `return`.

You can see below that `row 1` and `row 2` is a completed task and took `Jane Jetson` 10 seconds to do.

```
                   dt        name foo_id foo_role bikeId station_name station_id  action
1 2019-12-12 13:05:47 Jane Jetson 106337 Mechanic  12345   FooStation    1234.89 Release
2 2019-12-12 13:05:57 Jane Jetson 106337 Mechanic  12345   FooStation    1234.89  Return
3 2019-12-12 13:06:16    John Doe 106338 Mechanic  12345   FooStation    1234.89 Release
4 2019-12-12 13:06:19    John Doe 106338 Mechanic  12345   FooStation    1234.89  Return
5 2019-12-12 13:07:16    John Doe 106338 Mechanic  12345   FooStation    1234.89 Release
6 2019-12-12 14:07:16    John Doe 106338 Mechanic  56789 Some Station    4567.12 Release
```

**What I want to happen:**

- I want to know how long each `mechanic` took to repair the station using the `action` `Release` and then following a `Return`.
- If a `Release` does not have a `Return`, I want to take the `Sys.time()` and subtract it from `dt`. You'll see that `row 5` and `row 6`

I did this: *(I'm not 100% sure I need the previous action but I included in case it's needed.)*

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
foo = arrange(foo, foo_id, name, foo_role, bikeId, station_id) %>% 
  group_by(foo_id,name, foo_role, bikeId, station_name,station_id) %>%
  mutate(prev_dt = lag(dt, order_by = foo_id), 
         prev_action = lag(action, order_by=foo_id, default = 'NaN'))
foo$timediffsecs = as.numeric(difftime(foo$dt,foo$prev_dt,units='secs'))
```

```
> foo
# A tibble: 6 x 11
# Groups:   foo_id, name, foo_role, bikeId, station_name, station_id [3]
  dt                  name        foo_id foo_role bikeId station_name station_id action  prev_dt             prev_action timediffsecs
  <dttm>              <fct>        <int> <fct>     <int> <fct>             <dbl> <chr>   <dttm>              <chr>              <dbl>
1 2019-12-12 13:05:47 Jane Jetson 106337 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Release NA                  NaN                   NA
2 2019-12-12 13:05:57 Jane Jetson 106337 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Return  2019-12-12 13:05:47 Release               10
3 2019-12-12 13:06:16 John Doe    106338 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Release NA                  NaN                   NA
4 2019-12-12 13:06:19 John Doe    106338 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Return  2019-12-12 13:06:16 Release                3
5 2019-12-12 13:07:16 John Doe    106338 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Release 2019-12-12 13:06:19 Return                57
6 2019-12-12 14:07:16 John Doe    106338 Mechanic  56789 Some Station      4567. Release NA                  NaN                   NA
```

**The Problem**:

1. `row 5` is a new cycle because the `action` `Release` and `Return` has happened previously but `timediffsecs` recorded 57 secs.  In `row 5` `Prev_dt` and `prev_action` should be `NA` and `timediffsecs` = `Sys.time() - dt`.
2. `row 6` should have `timediffsecs` = `Sys.time() - dt`

**What I'm thinking could work:**

I changed `prev_action` NA to NaN so I could do some if else statements but I am not quite sure how to construct one for this. I want to change the NA in `prev_dt` to default to `dt` but there were problems doing that. The reason I want to try this is so I can use a conditional statement but if that's not needed, there's no need to change NA's.

**tl;dr:** I want `timediffsecs` to record the correct seconds. `row 5` and `row 6` have problems. `row 5` should be `Sys.time() - dt`. `row 6` I want to return `Sys.time() - dt`

**Data:**

```
structure(list(dt = structure(c(1576173947, 1576173957, 1576173976, 
1576173979, 1576174036, 1576177636), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Jane Jetson", 
"John Doe"), class = "factor"), foo_id = c(106337L, 106337L, 
106338L, 106338L, 106338L, 106338L), foo_role = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Mechanic", class = "factor"), 
    bikeId = c(12345L, 12345L, 12345L, 12345L, 12345L, 56789L
    ), station_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("FooStation", 
    "Some Station"), class = "factor"), station_id = c(1234.89, 
    1234.89, 1234.89, 1234.89, 1234.89, 4567.12), action = c("Release", 
    "Return", "Release", "Return", "Release", "Release")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How do you match `Release` with `Return` ? would they always be in consecutive rows following one another ?

Comment: Right now I’m grouping without including action. It won’t always be consecutive but a release at a station cannot happen again until it gets returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using `dplyr` could be to create group for each `name` (or `foo_id`) and everytime a `"Release"` happens. Within this group we calculate the difference between the time of `'Return'` and `'Release'` if `'Return'` is present or the difference between `'Release'` and current time.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(name, group = cumsum(action == "Release")) %>%
  mutate(timediffsecs = if (any(action == 'Return')) 
            dt[action == 'Return'] - dt[action == 'Release'] else Sys.time() - dt, 
         #If we want to replace Release values with NA
         timediffsecs  = replace(timediffsecs, n() > 1 & action == 'Release', NA))


#   dt                  name        foo_id foo_role bikeId station_name station_id action  group timediffsecs
#  <dttm>              <fct>        <int> <fct>     <int> <fct>             <dbl> <chr>   <int> <drtn>      
#1 2019-12-13 02:05:47 Jane Jetson 106337 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Release     1     NA secs 
#2 2019-12-13 02:05:57 Jane Jetson 106337 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Return      1     10 secs 
#3 2019-12-13 02:06:16 John Doe    106338 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Release     2     NA secs 
#4 2019-12-13 02:06:19 John Doe    106338 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Return      2      3 secs 
#5 2019-12-13 02:07:16 John Doe    106338 Mechanic  12345 FooStation        1235. Release     3 472603 secs 
#6 2019-12-13 03:07:16 John Doe    106338 Mechanic  56789 Some Station      4567. Release     4 469003 secs
```

Although this works for given example but may need some adjustments based on data.